# View SQLite database on Nexus 4?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am attempting to view a database for an app I am developing, I attempted to access it via the shell, however, it seems that in my Nexus 4's 'System/xBin' folder there is no 'sqlite3' file, and therefore unable to query my database to see its contents. Is there anyway I can do this? I am aware of an Eclipse plugin, but I am using Android Studio.

For example:

```
>adb -s DEVICE shell
>cd data/data/PROJECT/databases
>sqlite3 mydatabase.db
>sqlite3 not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see the database in the emulator ?? If yes, then probably you will not be able to see the database on the device unless you are using a device which is rooted. You will able to query the database though, but you will not be able to see it through file browser in ddms or through this command. First, please check if you can see it on emulator or not.

Comment: Yes, seems I need to use a device which is rooted and install sqlite on it, which is a shame. Thanks